# Django TestCase Warning: Converting column 'options' from VARCHAR to TEXT

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am new to Django testcase.

And I am using the django with mysql for backend. While I am trying to run django testcase for the particular app. I got the warning like below.

> **"Warning: Converting column 'options' from VARCHAR to TEXT"**

But this warning is stopping my testcase. Also not getting the result of testcases. At this time it created the test_db. Let me clear what happening at the time of testcase running and the details of this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [Django DB Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#notes-on-specific-fields) tells, that max_length=255 is guaranteed to work always for the **CharField, SlugField**.
So if it is needed to store large amount of value in those fields then, use **"TextField"** instead of **"CharField"**:

using:

```
options = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Instead of:

```
options = models.CharField(max_length=65536, blank=True)
```

now I fixed the error.